# The values of the combobox should be displayed in the textbox

Tags: c#, entity-framework, combobox, textbox

The values of the combo box should be displayed in the textbox.
There is a table in which the attribute "name" is displayed in the combo box. On the basis of the value that has been selected in the textbox should be derived attribute "price" of this value.The database is connected through a model ADO.NET. 
I think that the line CHANNEL type "ConnectionString = @" Data Source = .... "is not necessary, since the database I have already connected, everything works, everything is saved and changed. The only thing that's left is this conclusion I desired values in the textbox . I'm new to C #, I reviewed a bunch of lessons for my problem. They always use this connection string, which I do not need.
I used Google translator from Russian into English, so I'm sorry for you that is misunderstood.

```
   namespace test6
   {
       public partial class Form5 : Form
       {
        centrEntities db;
        public Form5()
    {

        InitializeComponent();
        FillCombobox();

    }

      private void Form5_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        db = new centrEntities();
        db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
        db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
        orderBindingSource.DataSource = db.order.ToList();

    }

     private void FillCombobox()
    {
        using (centrEntities c = new centrEntities())
        {

            comboService.DataSource = c.service.ToList();
            comboService.ValueMember = "serviceID";
            comboService.DisplayMember = "name";


         }
     }
```

[Table - values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lRZBv.png)

[how it looks.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xCy9s.png)

Answer (score 1):

I have add in your code a event `SelectedIndexChanged` to `ComboBox` `comboService` like this :

```
public partial class Form5 : Form
{
    centrEntities db;
    public Form5()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        FillCombobox();
        comboService.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(comboService_SelectedIndexChanged);
    }

    private void Form5_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        db = new centrEntities();
        db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
        db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
        orderBindingSource.DataSource = db.order.ToList();
    }

    private void FillCombobox()
    {
        using (centrEntities c = new centrEntities())
        {
            comboService.DataSource = c.service.ToList();
            comboService.ValueMember = "serviceID";
            comboService.DisplayMember = "name";
        }
    }

    private void comboService_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (comboService.SelectedValue != null)
        {
            using (centrEntities c = new centrEntities())
            {
                var price = (from serv in c.service
                             where serv.serviceID == Convert.ToInt32(comboService.SelectedValue)
                             select serv.price).SingleOrDefault();

                TextPriceName.Text = price.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks dude. great work. truth textbox displays are not "Price" and "serviceID".

Comment: change serviceId by Price in `comboService.ValueMember = "price"`;

Comment: Oh yes. I not noticed .
but the problem is solved by half . The fact is that when you select a value from combobox, displays the corresponding value in the textbox, thank you. But the transition to the next textbox, the data in the last two fields I've worked with (combobox, textbox) is not saved , and remain empty . So it should be in principle. Because by comboService.ValueMember = "serviceID" we maintain the selected service to the table with the order. You propose to keep on "price", although this value can not be saved in the table with an int value . I'm sorry that take up your time :)

Comment: I was trying to find another solution, I have change the code in answer, please test it! you use `comboService.ValueMember = "serviceID";` and change code of event `SelectedIndexChanged`.

Comment: came exclusion
 Expression LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method "Int32 ToInt32 (System.Object)", so it can not be transformed into an expression of the repository.

Comment: Try : `where serv.serviceID == comboService.SelectedValue` or `where serv.serviceID == (int)comboService.SelectedValue`

Comment: I have to leave my pc; I will call you later when I arrive!

Comment: 1) The operator ' == ' can not be applied to operands of type "Int" and "object"       2 ) Specified cast is not valid.

Comment: Okay, man. I 'll wait for you , and I will try to solve the problem himself .

Comment: Can you use `where serv.serviceID == 4` for test, and view if price 50 display in textbox price

Comment: It starts , but once again shows the price , only the first value and again when pressed nothing is stored in a text field . And yes , if you choose any value in a combobox " price " = 50 , the truth appears when you select any value in the drop-down list .

Comment: In contrast to the last attempt , the selected value is stored in the combo box . Not saved text field " price ."